# How to add value of v-rating vuetify into existing document in firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I'm using vuetify v-rating component inside a table. I want to add the rating value to each of the documents. So whenever user give a rating, it will add into document and this rating can be continuously update every time. I believe the way I do it is wrong but I don't really have a clue how to do it. Is there any ways to execute this? Thanks!

I'm using nuxt and firestore for my development.

[image: image of the table with the rating]

```html
<template>
           <div>
               <v-data-table
                dense
                :headers="headers"
                :items="subcontractorperformance"
                :options.sync="options"
                :loading="loading"
                class="elevation-1">
                   <template v-slot:[`item.rating`]="{ item }">
                       <div class="d-flex align-center justify-center">
                           <v-rating
                            v-model="rating"
                            color="yellow darken-3"
                            background-color="grey darken-1"
                            empty-icon="$ratingFull"
                            half-increments
                            hover
                            @input="updateInput(item)"
                            >
                           </v-rating>
                       </div>
                   </template>

                   <template v-slot:no-data>
                   <v-btn color="primary" @click="initialize"> Reset </v-btn>
                   </template>
   
               </v-data-table>
           </div>
       </template>
```

```js
 methods: {
        initialize() { //this functions loads the document into the table
            this.loading = true
            this.subcontractorperformance = []
            firestore
                .collection('registersubwork')
                .get()
                .then((querySnapshot) => {
                    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
                        this.subcontractorperformance.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
                        this.loading = false
                    })
                    console.log(this.subcontractorperformance)
                })
        },
        updateInput(value, item) { //this function to add rating to the document
            const itemId = this.editedItem.id
            console.log(itemId)
            firestore
                .collection('registersubwork')
                .doc(itemId)
                .update({ rating: value })
                .then(() => {
                    console.log(value, item);
                })  
        },
```

when refreshing the page, it gives me below error on the console:

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "value". Expected Number, got Array 

found in

---> <VRating>
       <VSimpleTable>
         <VData>
           <VDataTable>
             <Pages/subcontractorperformance.vue> at pages/subcontractorperformance.vue
               <Nuxt>
                 <VMain>
                   <VApp>
                     <Layouts/dashboard.vue> at layouts/dashboard.vue
                       <Root>
```

When I try to submit the rating, it sshows this error in the console:

```
prebuilt-306f43d8-45d6f0b9.js?a6a6:188 Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: No document to update: projects/bumiputera-contractor/databases/(default)/documents/registersubwork/vBxSMJvQtOc5x6s7mRc7
    at new n (prebuilt-306f43d8-45d6f0b9.js?a6a6:188)
    at eval (prebuilt-306f43d8-45d6f0b9.js?a6a6:9974)
    at Y.eval (prebuilt-306f43d8-45d6f0b9.js?a6a6:9922)
    at qb (index.esm.js?c7b2:328)
    at D (index.esm.js?c7b2:308)
    at Z.wa (index.esm.js?c7b2:1440)
    at sc (index.esm.js?c7b2:703)
    at tc (index.esm.js?c7b2:595)
    at M.k.Ia (index.esm.js?c7b2:565)
    at M.k.gb (index.esm.js?c7b2:505)
```

[[image: Firestore document]]

Edit 1:
Edit the latest code and errors that shown on the console

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the ID of document to update, use the `update()` method instead of `add()`:

```js
updateInput(value, item) {
  const itemId = this.editedItem.id
  console.log(itemId)
  firestore
    .collection('registersubwork')
    .doc(itemId)
    .set({ rating: value }, { merge: true })
    .then(() => {
      console.log(value, item);
    })  
},
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for the reply. But, unfortunately it gives me error ```[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "value". Expected Number, got Array``` What is the possible reason for that?

Comment: @SirAdley what error specifically? Can you update your question with latest code and a screenshot of the error?

Comment: my latest code I already edit to be same with what you answer above but it gives me error ```[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "value". Expected Number, got Array```

Comment: oh, when I submit the rating, this error ```Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: No document to update: projects/bumiputera-contractor/databases/(default)/documents/registersubwork/tK1qzgvSZGTq6fAzAJPw``` shows up on the console

Comment: @SirAdley that means the doc does not exist. Try using `.set({  rating: value }, { merge: true })` instead of `.update()`

Comment: Hi, no error this time but it creates a new document with rating as the map name (in the docs) and other values below the rating. I put the screenshot of it on the bottom of the question.